# PgAdmin 4 on Mac does not see the file system when trying to restore

Tags: macos, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Almost all folders in the root are marked with a red lock:[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try navigating them? AFAIK Red Lock means write protected and not read protected.